# Exit alternate screen after crashed ssh-tmux session

Tags: terminal, tmux, ncurses, tput

After I get disconnected from my tmux session over ssh (I have to use the ssh ~. command to exit), the mouse start displaying control characters like `80;31M65;80;31M65;` when I click or turn the wheel.

My internet search told me I am probably still in an **alternate screen** mode (triggered by tmux ?).

Someone suggested `tput rmcup`, but this does not work.
Now, the best I can do is close my terminal and open a new one.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Mouse is nothing to do with alternate screen, but you could be in alternate screen as well. The "reset" command is the easiest way to fix everything.

Comment: Indeed, the reset command worked, thanks!